# Android custom Seekbar with two thumbs view issues

Tags: android, view, android-fragments, seekbar, layout-inflater

I've been working with a custom Seekbar (with two thumbs) taken from [this site](http://www.kpbird.com/2011/05/android-seek-bar-with-two-thumb.html)

I've did a couple of modifications with the code to adapt it to my needs and be a little more modular (thumb positioning, drawing, etc.). I've noticed that it was a bit glitchy when activities were created. Here are the symptoms of my problem.

1. When used in an activity (Android 4.0.3 - Asus transformer)
   No issues at all, works 100%
2. When used in a fragment (Android 4.0.3 - Asus transformer)
   Gray and blue (progress) lines are centered, thumbs are at top of the seekbar frame. (cut in half). They still work (sliding left to right with the proper progress line in the center)
3. Same application and activity as #1 (Android 4.2.2 - Galaxy Tab 3 10.1)
   Both thumbs are in the center of the screen, you can't move them. Oddly, when you select one and move it from side to side, the seekbar value changed interface is called and the proper value is returned. When you release the selection of the thumb, the value sent to the listener returns to the center value.
4. Blank activity in a fresh application (Android 4.2.2 - Galaxy Tab 3 10.1)
   The seekbar works 100%
5. Same behavior as #1 and #2 with a Google Nexus 7 LTE (2013) on Android 4.3.1
   With this info, I can notice that the behavior varies from on activity to another depending on the amount of "stuff" included in it. I pretty sure it has to do with something about the measurements of the view. Probably the whole Init() method can be canned if the initialization is done properly overrinding the correct methods called during the creation of all the views in an activity or fragment.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Here is the complete Class:

```
public class SeekBarWithTwoThumb extends View {


    // ***************
    //     Members
    // ***************

// Drawing resources
private Bitmap thumb = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.seek_thumb_normal);
private Bitmap thumb_pressed = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.seek_thumb_pressed);
private Bitmap thumb_dissabled = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.seek_thumb_dissabled);

// Thumb's X coordinates and Y common coordinate
private int thumb1X, thumb2X;
private int thumbY;

// Thumb's return values
private int thumb1Value, thumb2Value;

// Thumb's dimensions
private int thumbHalfWidth;
private int thumbWidth;

// Selected thumb
private int selectedThumb;
private int lastSelectedThumb = 1;

// Paint object and listener
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private SeekBarChangeListener scl;

// Max value returned to listener
private int maxValue = 100;

// Thumb's enabled status
private boolean thumb1Enabled = true;
private boolean thumb2Enabled = false;

// Before init happens (not drawn in UI)
private boolean initDone = false;
private int thumb1Xpreset = 0, thumb2Xpreset = 50;

// ****************
//   Constructors
// ****************
public SeekBarWithTwoThumb(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public SeekBarWithTwoThumb(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SeekBarWithTwoThumb(Context context) {
    super(context);
}


// ***************
//    Overrides
// ***************
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if ((widthMeasureSpec != 0) && (heightMeasureSpec != 0)) {
        init();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Print the gray line in the back
    paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    canvas.drawLine(thumbHalfWidth, getHeight() / 2, getWidth() - thumbHalfWidth, getHeight() / 2, paint);

    // Print the progress line according seekbar settings
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setColor(0xFF33B5E5); // Hollow blue
    int drawThumbFirst = 0;     // Variable used declare which thumb will be drawn first
    if(thumb1Enabled && !thumb2Enabled) {
        canvas.drawLine(thumbHalfWidth, getHeight() / 2, thumb1X, getHeight() / 2, paint);
        drawThumbFirst = 2;
    } else if (!thumb1Enabled && thumb2Enabled){
        canvas.drawLine(thumbHalfWidth, getHeight() / 2, thumb2X, getHeight() / 2, paint);
        drawThumbFirst = 1;
    } else if (!thumb1Enabled && !thumb2Enabled) {
        // Do not draw, both are disabled
    } else if (selectedThumb == 1){
        canvas.drawLine(thumbHalfWidth, getHeight() / 2, thumb1X, getHeight() / 2, paint);
    } else if (selectedThumb == 2){
        canvas.drawLine(thumbHalfWidth, getHeight() / 2, thumb2X, getHeight() / 2, paint);
    } else if (lastSelectedThumb == 1){
        canvas.drawLine(thumbHalfWidth, getHeight() / 2, thumb1X, getHeight() / 2, paint);
    } else if (lastSelectedThumb == 2){
        canvas.drawLine(thumbHalfWidth, getHeight() / 2, thumb2X, getHeight() / 2, paint);
    }

    if (drawThumbFirst == 2){
        if (!thumb2Enabled) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(thumb_dissabled, thumb2X - thumbHalfWidth, thumbY,paint);
        } else if(selectedThumb == 2){
            canvas.drawBitmap(thumb_pressed, thumb2X - thumbHalfWidth, thumbY,paint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(thumb, thumb2X - thumbHalfWidth, thumbY,paint);
        }

        if (!thumb1Enabled) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(thumb_dissabled, thumb1X - thumbHalfWidth, thumbY,paint);
        } else if(selectedThumb == 1){
            canvas.drawBitmap(thumb_pressed, thumb1X - thumbHalfWidth, thumbY,paint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(thumb, thumb1X - thumbHalfWidth, thumbY,paint);
        }
    } else { // drawThumbFirst == 1 or 0 (0 has no importance since both thumbs either enabled or disabled)
        if (!thumb1Enabled) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(thumb_dissabled, thumb1X - thumbHalfWidth, thumbY,paint);
        } else if(selectedThumb == 1){
            canvas.drawBitmap(thumb_pressed, thumb1X - thumbHalfWidth, thumbY,paint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(thumb, thumb1X - thumbHalfWidth, thumbY,paint);
        }

        if (!thumb2Enabled) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(thumb_dissabled, thumb2X - thumbHalfWidth, thumbY,paint);
        } else if(selectedThumb == 2){
            canvas.drawBitmap(thumb_pressed, thumb2X - thumbHalfWidth, thumbY,paint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(thumb, thumb2X - thumbHalfWidth, thumbY,paint);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Get X coordinate of event
    int mx = (int) event.getX();

    switch (event.getAction()) {

    // Check if one of the thumbs are selected
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (mx >= thumb1X - thumbHalfWidth &&
            mx <= thumb1X + thumbHalfWidth &&
            thumb1Enabled) {
            selectedThumb = 1;
        } else if (mx >= thumb2X - thumbHalfWidth &&
                   mx <= thumb2X + thumbHalfWidth &&
                   thumb2Enabled) {
            selectedThumb = 2;
        }
        break;

    // If one of the thumbs are selected, move it
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        // Prevent thumb to get out of frame
        if(mx < thumbHalfWidth){
            mx = thumbHalfWidth;
        } else if(mx > (getWidth() - thumbHalfWidth)) {
            mx = getWidth() - thumbHalfWidth;
        }

        // Move the selected thumb to location
        if (selectedThumb == 1) {
            thumb1X = mx;
        } else if (selectedThumb == 2) {
            thumb2X = mx;
        }
        break;

    // Remove selection, if any
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        lastSelectedThumb = selectedThumb;
        selectedThumb = 0;
        break;
    }

    // Refresh
    invalidate();

    // Call listener if set
    if(scl != null){
        calculateThumbValue();
        scl.SeekBarValueChanged(thumb1Value,thumb2Value);
    }
    return true;
}


// ***************
//     Methods
// ***************
private void init() {
    // Fix layout if thumb image is to big
    Log.d("Custom Seekbars", "Height: " + thumb.getHeight() + ", " + getHeight());

    if (thumb.getHeight() > getHeight()){
        getLayoutParams().height = thumb.getHeight();
    }

    // Set the thumb's dimensions
    thumbHalfWidth = thumb.getWidth()/2;
    thumbWidth = thumb.getWidth();

    // Set the thumb's coordinates
    float workingWidth = getWidth() - thumbWidth;
    float scale1 = ((float)(thumb1Xpreset))/((float)(maxValue));
    float scale2 = ((float)(thumb2Xpreset))/((float)(maxValue));
    thumb1X = Math.round((scale1*workingWidth) + thumbHalfWidth);
    thumb2X = Math.round((scale2*workingWidth) + thumbHalfWidth);
    thumbY = (getHeight() / 2) - (thumb.getHeight() / 2);

    initDone = true;

    // Refresh
    invalidate();
}

public void setSeekBarChangeListener(SeekBarChangeListener scl){
    this.scl = scl;
}

private void calculateThumbValue(){
    thumb1Value = getThumb1Value();
    thumb2Value = getThumb2Value();
}

public interface SeekBarChangeListener{
    void SeekBarValueChanged(int Thumb1Value,int Thumb2Value);
}

public void setMax(int maxValue){
    if(initDone){
        int thumb1val = getThumb1Value();
        int thumb2val = getThumb1Value();
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
        setThumbValues(thumb1val, thumb2val);
    } else {
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
    }
}

// Disable & enable methods
public void setEnable(boolean value){
    thumb1Enabled = value;
    thumb2Enabled = value;
}
public void setDisable(boolean value){
    thumb1Enabled = !value;
    thumb2Enabled = !value;
}
public void setEnable(boolean thumb1, boolean thumb2){
    thumb1Enabled = thumb1;
    thumb2Enabled = thumb2;
}
public void setDisable(boolean thumb1, boolean thumb2){
    thumb1Enabled = !thumb1;
    thumb2Enabled = !thumb2;
}

// Thumb value setters and getters
public void setThumbValues(int thumb1, int thumb2){
    if(initDone){
        if(thumb1 >= maxValue){
            thumb1X = getWidth() - thumbHalfWidth;
        } else if(thumb1 <= 0) {
            thumb1X = thumbHalfWidth;
        } else {
            float workingWidth = getWidth() - thumbWidth;
            float scale = ((float)(thumb1))/((float)(maxValue));
            thumb1X = Math.round((scale*workingWidth) + thumbHalfWidth);
        }
        if(thumb2 >= maxValue){
            thumb2X = getWidth() - thumbHalfWidth;
        } else if(thumb2 <= 0) {
            thumb2X = thumbHalfWidth;
        } else {
            float workingWidth = getWidth() - thumbWidth;
            float scale = ((float)(thumb2))/((float)(maxValue));
            thumb2X = Math.round((scale*workingWidth) + thumbHalfWidth);
        }

        // Refresh
        invalidate();

        // Call listener if set
        if(scl != null){
            calculateThumbValue();
            scl.SeekBarValueChanged(thumb1Value,thumb2Value);
        }
    } else {
        if(thumb1 >= maxValue){
            thumb1Xpreset = maxValue;
        } else if(thumb1 <= 0) {
            thumb1Xpreset = 0;
        } else {
            thumb1Xpreset = thumb1;
        }

        if(thumb2 >= maxValue){
            thumb2Xpreset = maxValue;
        } else if(thumb2 <= 0) {
            thumb2Xpreset = 0;
        } else {
            thumb2Xpreset = thumb2;
        }
    }
}
public void setThumb1Value(int value){
    if(initDone){
        if(value >= maxValue){
            thumb1X = getWidth() - thumbHalfWidth;
        } else if(value <= 0) {
            thumb1X = thumbHalfWidth;
        } else {
            float workingWidth = getWidth() - thumbWidth;
            float scale = ((float)(value))/((float)(maxValue));
            thumb1X = Math.round((scale*workingWidth) + thumbHalfWidth);
        }

        // Refresh
        invalidate();

        // Call listener if set
        if(scl != null){
            calculateThumbValue();
            scl.SeekBarValueChanged(thumb1Value,thumb2Value);
        }
    } else {
        if(value >= maxValue){
            thumb1Xpreset = maxValue;
        } else if(value <= 0) {
            thumb1Xpreset = 0;
        } else {
            thumb1Xpreset = value;
        }
    }
}
public void setThumb2Value(int value){
    if(initDone){
        if(value >= maxValue){
            thumb2X = getWidth() - thumbHalfWidth;
        } else if(value <= 0) {
            thumb2X = thumbHalfWidth;
        } else {
            float workingWidth = getWidth() - thumbWidth;
            float scale = ((float)(value))/((float)(maxValue));
            thumb2X = Math.round((scale*workingWidth) + thumbHalfWidth);
        }

        // Refresh
        invalidate();

        // Call listener if set
        if(scl != null){
            calculateThumbValue();
            scl.SeekBarValueChanged(thumb1Value,thumb2Value);
        }
    } else {
        if(value >= maxValue){
            thumb2Xpreset = maxValue;
        } else if(value <= 0) {
            thumb2Xpreset = 0;
        } else {
            thumb2Xpreset = value;
        }
    }
}
public int getThumb1Value(){
    if(initDone){
        float workingWidth = getWidth() - thumbWidth;
        return Math.round((float)maxValue * ((float)(thumb1X - thumbHalfWidth)/workingWidth));
    } else {
        return thumb1Xpreset;
    }
}
public int getThumb2Value(){
    if(initDone){
        float workingWidth = getWidth() - thumbWidth;
        return Math.round((float)maxValue * ((float)(thumb2X - thumbHalfWidth)/workingWidth));
    } else {
        return thumb2Xpreset;
    }
}

}
```